# Does there exist a group with two such subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Does there exist a group $G$ with the following properties? ($N_G$ is the normalizer)

- $\exists H,F\leq G$ such that there is no injection $i:F\to H$ or $i:H\to F$
- $N_G(H)/H$ and $N_G(F)/F$ are both abelian
- $N_G(F\cap H)/F\cap H$ is not abelian

This problem emerged from a disagreement I had with a professor about wether we can omit the normality condition in the definition of a Universal Abelian Covering but no Algebraic Topology knowledge is required to tackle it of course.

Comment: To be clear, what precisely do you mean by "injection"? Just an injective function, or a function which sends $x \mapsto x$ specifically?

Comment: I would look for a non abelian group such that $F\cap H =\{e\}$ and self normalizing $F$ and $H$. Maybe cut a maximal toral subgroup of e.g. $SL(n)$ in two.

Comment: $G=S_3$, $H=S_2$, $F=A_3$?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer specifically $x\to x$

Comment: I think @verret 's answer checks out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest nonabelian group is already an example: $G=S_3$, $H=S_2$, $F=A_3$.
More generally, for $n\geq 3$, you can take $G=S_n$, $H=S_{n-1}$, $F=C_n$.